# How do I show that a function of an intersection of sets is not always equal to the intersection of a function of sets?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

I'm currently taking this college calculus course, and this exercise has stumped me. It is in German, but hopefully what it's asking is fairly clear.

[image: Image of the problem]

To summarize, the problem first asks me to prove that the preimage of an intersection of a family of sets is equal to the intersection of a preimage of a family of sets, where f: A -> B and Ui is a family of subsets of B. To do this, I just gave the general example of x being an arbitrary element of A, which means that x is an element of the preimage of the intersection, which means for all values of i f(x) is an element of Ui, which means x is an element of the intersection of the preimage of Ui.

Image of my answer cause I can't figure out MathJax:
[image: Answer]

Then the problem asks to show that for a family Vi, a subset of A, an image of the intersection of a family of sets is not in general equal to the intersection of an image of a family of sets.

Yet, for every example formula and sets I can conjure up, I always seem to prove that the two sides are in fact equal. No amount of coaxing and complaining on Bing or ChatGPT causes them to bring an example up either - they just keep giving examples where the two sides are equal.

So, is this a typo from my professor and this expression actually is generally correct, or am I missing something? What family of sets and functions would make these not equal?

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Guide:

Let $V_1$ be the set of positive integers, let $V_2$ be the set of negative integers. By designing my set to be so, note that $V_1 \cap V_2 =\emptyset$ and hence $f(V_1 \cap V_2)=\emptyset$.

Now, can you design your function such that $f(V_1)$ and $f(V_2)$ has non-empty intersects?

Answer (score 3):

**First question.**
This can be proved by double inclusion. If the sets $U_i \subset B$ are all chosen to be empty, then the statement is straightforward.

Now, let's assume that there exists $a \in f^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}U_i\right)$, which is restated as $f(a) \in \bigcap_{i\in I}U_i$. In consequence, $f(a) \in U_i \;\forall i \in I$, which is equivalent to $a \in f^{-1}(U_i) \;\forall i \in I$, hence finally $a \in \bigcap_{i \in I}f^{-1}(U_i)$, which permits to conclude $f^{-1}\left(\bigcap_{i\in I}U_i\right) \subset \bigcap_{i \in I}f^{-1}(U_i)$.

I let you verify the reverse inclusion with the help of a similar proof.

**Second question.**
You only need a counterexample. Let's take $a_1,a_2 \in A$ with $a_1 \neq a_2$ but $f(a_1) = f(a_2) =: b \in B$. Then,
$$
f(\{a_1\} \cap \{a_2\}) = f(\emptyset) = \emptyset
$$
but
$$
f(\{a_1\}) \cap f(\{a_2\}) = \{b\} \cap \{b\} = \{b\}.
$$
Actually, this equality is a "fancy" way to define injectivity.

Comment: Super helpful, thanks! I'm trying to do the reverse inclusion now, but having a little trouble with the first step. a is an element of the intersection of the inverse function of Ui... and then what's the next substitution?

Answer (score 1):

A good idea when you can't come up with a counterexample to a statement is to try *proving* the statement instead, and examining where exactly in that process you get stuck. Because that is the point where your counterexample can be found.

So let's try it: we want to prove that $f(\bigcap V_i)=\bigcap f(V_i)$. Set equality is usually proved by showing that each set is contained in the other. So first step, let's prove $f(\bigcap V_i)\subseteq\bigcap f(V_i)$.

This really means that if $x$ is an element of every $V_i$, then $f(x)$ is an element of every $f(V_i)$. This is clearly true (but you can go through it to exercise).

So now let's prove $f(\bigcap V_i)\supseteq\bigcap f(V_i)$. This means that if every image contains a certain element $y$, then there is a preimage of that element that is contained in every $V_i$. And certainly, every $V_i$ does contain *some* preimage of $y$. So our statement to prove *would* be true if that preimage were always the same. But what if there were *different* preimages of $y$? Then this wouldn't work. So how about trying a function as a counterexample which has more than one preimage for some of its images? That is, a non-injective function?

For instance, $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R, x\mapsto x^2$. Then take $V_1=(-\infty,0]$ and $V_2=[0,\infty)$. Then $V_\cap V_2=\{0\}$, whose image is $\{0\}$. But $f(V_1)=f(V_2)=[0,\infty)$, so $f(V_1)\cap f(V_2)=[0,\infty)\neq \{0\}$. A counterexample!